# Determine if city in input is valid

Tags: php, city

I want to determine if a city user entered in textbox is valid, and I have this code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$check = checkCityOrCountry('Sweden');
if($check === false)    
    echo 'Not Valid country';
else
{
    echo 'Valid: <pre>';
    print_r($check);
    echo '</pre>';
}

function checkCityOrCountry($name)
{
    $checkCity = $name;
    $checkCity = mb_strtolower($checkCity, "UTF-8");

    $countries = vkapi('database.getCountries', array(
            'need_all' => 1,
            'count' => 1000), null, true);
    $countries = $countries['response'];

    $validString = false;

    $cCnt = count($countries);
    for($i = 0; $i < $cCnt; ++$i)
    {
        $title = mb_strtolower($countries[$i]['title'], "UTF-8");
        if(mb_strpos($title, $checkCity, 0, 'UTF-8') !== false)
        {
            $validString = $countries[$i];
            break;
        }

        /*search by cities too, but extremely long*/
        // $cities = vkapi('database.getCities', array(
        //     'country_id' => $countries[$i]['cid'],
        //     'q' => $checkCity,
        //     'count' => 1000), null, true);
        // $cities = $cities['response'];
        // if(count($cities) > 0)
        // {
        //     $validString = $cities;
        //     break;
        // }
    }

    return $validString;
}
/**
 * @function vkapi          Perform a request to api VK
 * @param  string $method   Name of method
 * @param  array   $params  Post parameters
 * @param  string  $token   Secure token if you need it
 * @param  boolean $array   If = true, will returns an array, in other case - an object
 * @return array            Result
 */
function vkapi($method, $params = array(), $token=null, $array=false) {
    try
    {
        $rid = 0;
        if(isset($token))
            $params["access_token"] = $token;

        $params['lang'] = 'en';
        $paramstr = http_build_query($params);
        $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/" . $method . "?" . $paramstr;

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        if($array == true)
        {
            $result = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
        }

        return $result;

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        throw new Exception('VK API: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But this code is not working, whatever I enter in 
$check = checkCityOrCountry('Sweden'); I always get "Not Valid country" output.

Comment: Are your `$title`s what you're expecting them to be inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the function like this:

```
$check = checkCityOrCountry('Sweden');
echo var_dump($check); // true

$check = checkCityOrCountry('foo');
echo var_dump($check); // false

function checkCityOrCountry($name)
{
    $countries = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?need_all=1&count=1000&lang=en');
    $arr = json_decode($countries, true);
    foreach ($arr['response'] as $country) {
        if (mb_strtolower($country['title']) === mb_strtolower($name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

...if you don't have a specific reason for using cURL, it's simpler to just use file_get_contents(). Also, with json_decode() if you want to process the data as an array, the second parameter should be 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

if you check https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?need_all=1 Sweden does not exist there..

EDITED: THE CORRECT URL IS https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?need_all=1&count=1000&lang=en

Comment: Hmm. Do you know any other way to check if country/city exists? Also, I tried to enter Belgium but the output is same.

Comment: The URL I get returned by function vkapi() is https://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?need_all=1&count=1000&lang=en, and Sweden is in the array. The problem is in checkCityOfCountry() where $validString = false; is set but the array check isn't matching properly

Comment: No matter what input is, the output is always the same - Not valid @Ardit Meti yeah didn't see your URL correctly.

Comment: can you var_dump this line : $countries = $countries['response'];

Comment: var_dump returns NULL. @Michael exactly, it's NULL.

Comment: then check your curl in vkapi function as Michael said. Or try using guzzle for HTTP requests.